# Rails select form helper needs to save multiple attribute values of one object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a form where I'm creating an interview for a job posting and one of the fields is a dropdown where I select the candidate (from a list of candidates created on another page) that I plan to interview.

So far I'm able to save the details of the interview as well as the candidates name, but I also want to save the candidates id. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Currently I have

```
= select("interview", "interviewee_name", Candidate.order('last_name ASC').collect {|c| [c.fullname]})
```

Somehow I need to find a way to retrieve and save the correct value to candidate_id.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I have a similar need, but I am not using RoR, just a `haml` compiler powered by `ruby`, but `ruby` is not my development language, only a tool that processes haml into html. Could you replace the expression `Candidate.order('last_name ASC').collect {|c| [c.fullname]}` with some hard-code values that would work just as well? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= select("interview", "interviewee_name", Candidate.order('last_name ASC').collect{|c| [c.fullname, c.id]})
```

**UPD**

Then (if you really need to store its name) in model add callback:

```
class Interview < AR::Base
  before_save :set_candidate_name
  belongs_to :candidate

private

  def set_candidate_name
    self.interviewee_name = self.candidate.fullname
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that before. The candidate's id ends up being saved to the interviewee_name field. My goal is to save both the candidate's name to interviewee_name, and the candidate's id to candidate_id.

Comment: You don't have to save candidate's name in interviews table. candidate_id is enough.

Comment: aah, yup I was making this unnecessarily complicated for myself (and now I'm very embarrassed...haha). I ended up using your suggestion but tweaked it
= select("interview", "candidate_id", Candidate.order('last_name ASC').collect{|c| [c.fullname, c.id]}).. Then whenever I needed to display the name under an interview, I just used @interview.candidate.fullname. Thanks for getting the gears going! :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use javascript to do this - basically put a click handler on the select element and make an ajax call to the server to retrieve the candidate name from the id.  Then populate the name field in the callback.

I think I have some sample code somewhere if you are using jquery ...